# PHPBB How do you load files through public_html

Tags: php, html, phpbb

I am doing a school project but I am having some trouble with PHPBB because I cant get it to load files through public_html. I would appreciate some help with this thanks. If you have any questions I will happily answer them.

```
<?php include("/home/***/public_html/application/config/autoload.php");?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="{S_CONTENT_DIRECTION}" lang="{S_USER_LANG}" xml:lang="{S_USER_LANG}">
<head>

    <div class='title-box'>
        <img src='http://www.berkley.school.nz/wp-content/themes/sparky/img/logo.min.png'>
        </div>


    <div class="header">

        <div class="header_left_box">

        <ul id="menu">

            <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "forum")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>forum">Forum</a>
            </li>

            <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "helpcenter")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>helpcenter">Help Center</a>
            </li>

            <?php if (Session::get('user_logged_in') == true):?>

            <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "dashboard")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>dashboard">Dashboard</a>
            </li>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (Session::get('user_logged_in') == true):?>

                <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "login")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >

                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/showprofile">My Account</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "login")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/changeaccounttype">Change account type</a>
                        </li>

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "login")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/uploadavatar">Upload an avatar</a>
                        </li>

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "login")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/editusername">Edit my username</a>
                        </li>

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "login")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/edituseremail">Edit my email</a>
                        </li>

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "login")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/changepassword">Edit my password</a>
                        </li>

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "login")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>login/logout">Logout</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (Session::get('user_type') == 1):?>

                <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "student")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >

                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>student">Student</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "student")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>student"></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (Session::get('user_type') == 2):?>
                <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "student")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >

                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>student">Student</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "student")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>student"></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "teacher")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >

                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>teacher">Teacher</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "teacher")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>teacher"></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (Session::get('user_type') == 3):?>
                <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "student")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >

                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>student">Student</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "student")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>student"></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "teacher")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >

                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>teacher">Teacher</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "teacher")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>teacher"></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "admin")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >

                    <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>admin">Admin</a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveController($filename, "admin")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
                            <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>admin"></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

            <?php endif; ?>



        </ul>

        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header">

        <div class="header_right_box">

        <ul id="menu">

         <?php if (Session::get('user_logged_in') == false):?>
        <li <?php if ($this->checkForActiveControllerAndAction($filename, "login/index")) { echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >
        <a href="<?php echo URL; ?>">Login</a>
        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

            <?php endif; ?>



        </ul>

        </div>

        <?php if (Session::get('user_logged_in') == true): ?>


            <div class="header_right_box">

                <div class="namebox">
                    Hello <?php echo Session::get('user_name'); ?>!
                </div>

                <div class="avatar">

                    <?php if (USE_GRAVATAR) { ?>

                        <img src='<?php echo Session::get('user_gravatar_image_url'); ?>'

                             style='width:<?php echo AVATAR_SIZE; ?>px; height:<?php echo AVATAR_SIZE; ?>px;' />

                    <?php } else { ?>

                        <img src='<?php echo Session::get('user_avatar_file'); ?>'

                             style='width:<?php echo AVATAR_SIZE; ?>px; height:<?php echo AVATAR_SIZE; ?>px;' />

                    <?php } ?>

                </div>

            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="clear-both"></div>

    </div>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset={S_CONTENT_ENCODING}" />
<meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="{S_USER_LANG}" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta name="resource-type" content="document" />
<meta name="distribution" content="global" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
{META}
<title>{SITENAME} &bull; <!-- IF S_IN_MCP -->{L_MCP} &bull; <!-- ELSEIF S_IN_UCP -->{L_UCP} &bull; <!-- ENDIF -->{PAGE_TITLE}</title>

<!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS -->
    <!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS_OVERALL --><link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{L_FEED} - {SITENAME}" href="{U_FEED}" /><!-- ENDIF -->
    <!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS_NEWS --><link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{L_FEED} - {L_FEED_NEWS}" href="{U_FEED}?mode=news" /><!-- ENDIF -->
    <!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS_FORUMS --><link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{L_FEED} - {L_ALL_FORUMS}" href="{U_FEED}?mode=forums" /><!-- ENDIF -->
    <!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS_TOPICS --><link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{L_FEED} - {L_FEED_TOPICS_NEW}" href="{U_FEED}?mode=topics" /><!-- ENDIF -->
    <!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS_TOPICS_ACTIVE --><link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{L_FEED} - {L_FEED_TOPICS_ACTIVE}" href="{U_FEED}?mode=topics_active" /><!-- ENDIF -->
    <!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS_FORUM and S_FORUM_ID --><link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{L_FEED} - {L_FORUM} - {FORUM_NAME}" href="{U_FEED}?f={S_FORUM_ID}" /><!-- ENDIF -->
    <!-- IF S_ENABLE_FEEDS_TOPIC and S_TOPIC_ID --><link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{L_FEED} - {L_TOPIC} - {TOPIC_TITLE}" href="{U_FEED}?f={S_FORUM_ID}&amp;t={S_TOPIC_ID}" /><!-- ENDIF -->
<!-- ENDIF -->

<!--
    phpBB style name: prosilver
    Based on style:   prosilver (this is the default phpBB3 style)
    Original author:  Tom Beddard ( http://www.subBlue.com/ )
    Modified by:
-->

<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    var jump_page = '{LA_JUMP_PAGE}:';
    var on_page = '{ON_PAGE}';
    var per_page = '{PER_PAGE}';
    var base_url = '{A_BASE_URL}';
    var style_cookie = 'phpBBstyle';
    var style_cookie_settings = '{A_COOKIE_SETTINGS}';
    var onload_functions = new Array();
    var onunload_functions = new Array();

    <!-- IF S_USER_PM_POPUP and S_NEW_PM -->
        var url = '{UA_POPUP_PM}';
        window.open(url.replace(/&amp;/g, '&'), '_phpbbprivmsg', 'height=225,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes, width=400');
    <!-- ENDIF -->

    /**
    * Find a member
    */
    function find_username(url)
    {
        popup(url, 760, 570, '_usersearch');
        return false;
    }

    /**
    * New function for handling multiple calls to window.onload and window.unload by pentapenguin
    */
    window.onload = function()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < onload_functions.length; i++)
        {
            eval(onload_functions[i]);
        }
    };

    window.onunload = function()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < onunload_functions.length; i++)
        {
            eval(onunload_functions[i]);
        }
    };

// ]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{T_SUPER_TEMPLATE_PATH}/styleswitcher.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{T_SUPER_TEMPLATE_PATH}/forum_fn.js"></script>

<link href="{T_THEME_PATH}/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" title="printonly" />
<link href="{T_STYLESHEET_LINK}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />

<link href="{T_THEME_PATH}/normal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="A" />
<link href="{T_THEME_PATH}/medium.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="A+" />
<link href="{T_THEME_PATH}/large.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="A++" />

<!-- IF S_CONTENT_DIRECTION eq 'rtl' -->
    <link href="{T_THEME_PATH}/bidi.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<!-- ENDIF -->

</head>

<body id="phpbb" class="section-{SCRIPT_NAME} {S_CONTENT_DIRECTION}">

<div id="wrap">
    <a id="top" name="top" accesskey="t"></a>
    <div id="page-header">
        <div class="headerbar">
            <div class="inner"><span class="corners-top"><span></span></span>

            <div id="site-description">
                <a href="{U_INDEX}" title="{L_INDEX}" id="logo">{SITE_LOGO_IMG}</a>
                <h1>{SITENAME}</h1>
                <p>{SITE_DESCRIPTION}</p>
                <p class="skiplink"><a href="#start_here">{L_SKIP}</a></p>
            </div>

        <!-- IF S_DISPLAY_SEARCH and not S_IN_SEARCH -->
            <div id="search-box">
                <form action="{U_SEARCH}" method="get" id="search">
                <fieldset>
                    <input name="keywords" id="keywords" type="text" maxlength="128" title="{L_SEARCH_KEYWORDS}" class="inputbox search" value="<!-- IF SEARCH_WORDS-->{SEARCH_WORDS}<!-- ELSE -->{L_SEARCH_MINI}<!-- ENDIF -->" onclick="if(this.value=='{LA_SEARCH_MINI}')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='{LA_SEARCH_MINI}';" />
                    <input class="button2" value="{L_SEARCH}" type="submit" /><br />
                    <a href="{U_SEARCH}" title="{L_SEARCH_ADV_EXPLAIN}">{L_SEARCH_ADV}</a> {S_SEARCH_HIDDEN_FIELDS}
                </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        <!-- ENDIF -->

            <span class="corners-bottom"><span></span></span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="inner"><span class="corners-top"><span></span></span>

            <ul class="linklist navlinks">
                <li class="icon-home"><a href="{U_INDEX}" accesskey="h">{L_INDEX}</a> <!-- BEGIN navlinks --> <strong>&#8249;</strong> <a href="{navlinks.U_VIEW_FORUM}">{navlinks.FORUM_NAME}</a><!-- END navlinks --></li>

                <li class="rightside"><a href="#" onclick="fontsizeup(); return false;" onkeypress="return fontsizeup(event);" class="fontsize" title="{L_CHANGE_FONT_SIZE}">{L_CHANGE_FONT_SIZE}</a></li>

                <!-- IF U_EMAIL_TOPIC --><li class="rightside"><a href="{U_EMAIL_TOPIC}" title="{L_EMAIL_TOPIC}" class="sendemail">{L_EMAIL_TOPIC}</a></li><!-- ENDIF -->
                <!-- IF U_EMAIL_PM --><li class="rightside"><a href="{U_EMAIL_PM}" title="{L_EMAIL_PM}" class="sendemail">{L_EMAIL_PM}</a></li><!-- ENDIF -->
                <!-- IF U_PRINT_TOPIC --><li class="rightside"><a href="{U_PRINT_TOPIC}" title="{L_PRINT_TOPIC}" accesskey="p" class="print">{L_PRINT_TOPIC}</a></li><!-- ENDIF -->
                <!-- IF U_PRINT_PM --><li class="rightside"><a href="{U_PRINT_PM}" title="{L_PRINT_PM}" accesskey="p" class="print">{L_PRINT_PM}</a></li><!-- ENDIF -->
            </ul>

            <!-- IF not S_IS_BOT and S_USER_LOGGED_IN -->
            <ul class="linklist leftside">
                <li class="icon-ucp">
                    <a href="{U_PROFILE}" title="{L_PROFILE}" accesskey="e">{L_PROFILE}</a>
                        <!-- IF S_DISPLAY_PM --> (<a href="{U_PRIVATEMSGS}">{PRIVATE_MESSAGE_INFO}</a>)<!-- ENDIF -->
                    <!-- IF S_DISPLAY_SEARCH --> &bull;
                    <a href="{U_SEARCH_SELF}">{L_SEARCH_SELF}</a>
                    <!-- ENDIF -->
                    <!-- IF U_RESTORE_PERMISSIONS --> &bull;
                    <a href="{U_RESTORE_PERMISSIONS}">{L_RESTORE_PERMISSIONS}</a>
                    <!-- ENDIF -->
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- ENDIF -->

            <ul class="linklist rightside">
                <li class="icon-faq"><a href="{U_FAQ}" title="{L_FAQ_EXPLAIN}">{L_FAQ}</a></li>
                <!-- IF not S_IS_BOT -->
                    <!-- IF S_DISPLAY_MEMBERLIST --><li class="icon-members"><a href="{U_MEMBERLIST}" title="{L_MEMBERLIST_EXPLAIN}">{L_MEMBERLIST}</a></li><!-- ENDIF -->
                    <!-- IF not S_USER_LOGGED_IN and S_REGISTER_ENABLED and not (S_SHOW_COPPA or S_REGISTRATION) --><li class="icon-register"><a href="{U_REGISTER}">{L_REGISTER}</a></li><!-- ENDIF -->
                    <li class="icon-logout"><a href="{U_LOGIN_LOGOUT}" title="{L_LOGIN_LOGOUT}" accesskey="x">{L_LOGIN_LOGOUT}</a></li>
                <!-- ENDIF -->
            </ul>

            <span class="corners-bottom"><span></span></span></div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <a name="start_here"></a>
    <div id="page-body">
        <!-- IF S_BOARD_DISABLED and S_USER_LOGGED_IN and (U_MCP or U_ACP) -->
        <div id="information" class="rules">
            <div class="inner"><span class="corners-top"><span></span></span>
                <strong>{L_INFORMATION}:</strong> {L_BOARD_DISABLED}
            <span class="corners-bottom"><span></span></span></div>
        </div>
        <!-- ENDIF -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the path in quotes:

```
<?php include('/home/***/public_html/application/config/autoload.php');?>
```

or

```
<?php include("/home/***/public_html/application/config/autoload.php");?>
```

Comment: I did what you said but it still didnt load it

Comment: It's likely there's a new error; your code is an absolute mess — Please provide an error log.

Comment: Do u know PHPBB coding

Comment: php has been enabled an that is just a test menu and when it trys to load ?php include("/home/***/public_html/application/config/autoload.php");?> it doesn't find it

Comment: You need to use the path of `autoload.php`. I seriously doubt your path is `/home/***/public_html` with asterisks?

Comment: when i try to load a page it loads in the forum folder to get out of that i use /home/<username>/public_html

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of major issues with the code you've posted.

1. As identified by l'L'l, your `include()` syntax is incorrect.
2. You are attempting to mix PHP code with phpBB template syntax (e.g, `{VARIABLE}`, `<!-- IF CONDITION -->`). They are not compatible.
3. Your HTML is badly disordered; it has a bunch of content in `<head>`. This doesn't belong here.

It looks as though you may be trying to do too much, too fast here. Sit down and learn PHP properly before you continue.

Comment: i am trying to get require_once or include to work because that code is just a test code when it works it will display menu all ready and the autoload loads a style configs and classes

Comment: @user3818340, you can't expect things to work if you don't take suggestions and fix what is obviously wrong. As duskwuff mentioned you've got `html` in your `<head>` tag and many other issues on top of that. Considering you had multiple errors in the first line of your `.php` you might want to step back and consider learning why. At the least, even a very basic understanding of `php` might help you tremendously.